# Android - Display Image from url on textview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to put the image from url and display it to textview. when i use case 2, the image display perfectly,

but in case 1 not. there is error "unknown protocol: data" and "W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color"

```
        //case 1
//          String base_url = "<p>Image 1 : <img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk...

        //case 2
        String base_url = "<p>Image 1 : <img src=\"http://example.com/android/tryout/logo.png\"></img></p>";

        Spanned span2 = Html.fromHtml(base_url,getImageHTML(),null);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.target);
        tv.setText(span2);
```

and this is my function

```
public Html.ImageGetter getImageHTML() {

    Html.ImageGetter imageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            try {
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(new URL(source).openStream(), "src");
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

                return drawable;
            } catch(IOException exception) {
                Log.v("IOException", exception.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

    return imageGetter;
}
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: inside `getDrawable` you have to decode your base64 text if `source` starts with "data:image/jpeg"

Comment: oh i see. how can I decode this sir ?

Comment: sorry, I'm completely beginner in android. i try this code, but the app stopped working

 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(source, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

                    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(new URL(decodedByte.toString()).openStream(), "src");
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

                    return drawable;

Comment: see `Base64InputStream`

Comment: still getting error

Comment: error? what error?

Comment: how to use base64inputstream in this case. i'm so confused

Comment: `new Base64InputStream(new new ByteArrayInputStream(base64.getBytes()))` for example, where `base64` is a String holding your base64 encoded data

Comment: there is note "base64InputStream(InputStream, int) can not be applied to (ByteArrayinputStream)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126070/discussion-between-ahmad-budi-u-and-pskink).

Comment: Could u please add the solution of this question..That will helpful for other and me also :P