# Display image from URL in textview Android

Tags: java, android

How do I display image from url in textview?
the url is say http://demo/image.jpeg and I have a text view.
[Android - Display Image from url on textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122620/android-display-image-from-url-on-textview)
this link the fromhtml is deprecated.
Picasso is a good way, but I have to use textview and image is from url.
TextView.setDrawables won't work I guess.

Comment: Take an ImageView if you have an image.

Comment: You could try and convert it to a Drawable, but why can't you just use an ImageView?

Comment: Get a bitmap from source URL then you can use ImageSpan with Bitmap. When you get an image as bitmap, follow these answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25522359/1214847). As you wanted, you will see image in a textView.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Glide, it's much better than Picasso in my opinion.

```
Glide.with(this)
.load(textView.getText().toString())
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: load image into textview, not into imageview